# Laravel API integration in flutter problem

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, integration

I have 3 screens:

1. Register
2. Login
3. Homepage

First, Register will simply ask users for their details and upon successfully entering the details it will redirect to the login. the login will ask for their credentials and be redirected to homePage.

In the backend (Laravel), the register API and Login API is working fine but the problem is with the HomePage API where it will not ask for user details, it's a `get` method where it will return the details upon checking where the user is logged-In or not.

I have used `SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` for storing `Key` and
`csrf`.

```
  _getKey() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    key = prefs.getString('key');
  }

  _getCSRF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    csrf = prefs.getString('csrf');
    print(csrf);
  }
  _setAuthHeaders() => {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $key'
      };
  getData() async {
    await _getCSRF();
    await _getKey();
    print(_setAuthHeaders());
    String uri = "$baseUrlUser/user_bal";
    try {
      return await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: _setAuthHeaders());
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

Response of the url in my homePage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter ( 3457): <html lang="en">
I/flutter ( 3457): <head>
I/flutter ( 3457): <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter ( 3457): <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
I/flutter ( 3457): <meta name="csrf-token" content="6PjARs1hf0tx66pfM7WGh0ct7VNBxbhXDYElvu6u" />
I/flutter ( 3457): <title>Retailer Login | xxxxxx</title>
I/flutter ( 3457):
I/flutter ( 3457): <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
I/flutter ( 3457):
I/flutter ( 3457): <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
I/flutter ( 3457):
I/flutter ( 3457): <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
I/flutter ( 3457):
I/flutter ( 3457): <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
```

[This is header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noqIz.png)

Please help.

Comment: What's in the debug console?...the response?

Comment: Upon hitting the `getData()` method in homeScreen. It will just showing me login page of the backend in response.

Comment: what's the statusCode?

Comment: statusCode is `200`

Comment: Maybe somethings wrong with your laravel api

Comment: If there may be a problem with my backend then how come it's working in Postman?

Comment: what json response are you expecting.., are you getting it in postmen?

Comment: Yes, It is working fine in postman.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in, a "set-cookie" is returned with the response as a header that holds information on the laravel session.
[Set-cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPuXP.png)

You need to pass that value on your headers with your GET requests.

Comment: Can you please how me code that will be helpful? Thanks

Comment: Hey, I have done that but it's showing me same. I passed the set-cookie part to get request but its still showing me this.

Comment: add value to the request header as "cookie", not "set-cookie"